# General location model

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, continuous-data, joint-distribution

Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be categorical random variables with $3$ and $2$ categories, respectively. Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be $2$ continuous random variables. Define completely the GLOM (general location model) for the joint distribution of $Z=(Z_1,Z_2)^T$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)^T$

I couldn't solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @gloomy, but we treat them differently (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Please tell us what you understand & have tried already, & we'll provide some hints to help get you unstuck.

Comment: I was absent this lecture, and I dont have any idea about GLOM. I have checked some online books but they didnt help me.